# Modeless (non-modal) dialog in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to create modeless dialog i.e. the dialog which allow user to work on parent component even if the dialog is on the screen and don't close when clicked outside of the dialog.

is there anyway?

```
openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

    this.dialog.open(CourseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

here `dialogConfig.disableClose = true;` makes dialog modal, I want to know if there is any property or setting which i can use to make this dialog non-modal.

example of modeless dialog the style dialog in MS word. I am able to type text even if styles dialog is on screen.
[image]

Comment: can anyone please explain me what is wrong with my question?

Comment: If I understand correctly @MohiniMhetre in case your modal doesn't behave like one, you can just use something like a bootstrap card with minimal box shadow and position css and trigger it conditionally, just to mock it like a dialog !

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-894yyy please check this example

```
export class NgbdModalConfig {
  constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    // customize default values of modals used by this component tree
    config.backdrop = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
  }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
}
```

Comment: As per our requirement I need to show dialog on the screen which should be movable and modeless, I can't use  alert or popver. I am not sure about div to be shown on the top, the look and feel won't be like a dialog.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre Why did you accept this answer?  Testing the link given, it's not movable and you can't interact with the main window while it's up, which was the whole point of your question, if I understand.  Did you figure out a way to make it do what you needed?

Comment: @Erhannis I am not sure about the link given, but I had used config given by dora2pro and dialog became modeless. That's why I accepted that answer. Unfortunately now I will not be able to show my exact config because I have switched in other company. May be you can try combination of config given in question and the answer, which should work.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre Huh, weird.  The link has the same code as the answer does - I don't know why it would work differently.  But, as long as you got it working, I guess.  I ended up just making a div with position: absolute and turning it on and off with angular.

Comment: The Stackblitz example uses NG Bootstrap: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap - if you don't have it installed, it won't work like the example.